# Add entities to a world conditionally in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm very new to actionscript 3, and only learned rudimentary coding through YouTube. Regardless, I'm using FlashPunk to alleviate pain, and it seems to have useful tools.

In my Level, which extends the World class, the constructor adds two entities: the Player and the Enemy, which then play around and do things. I want to be able to add additional instances of the Enemy entity, or perhaps remove and re-add the player (so as to reset health and position) with a key input. If I try the following in Main.as

```
Input.define("Reset", Key.R);
```

followed by the following in Level.as

```
    public function Level() 
    {
        if (Input.pressed("Reset"))
        {
            add(new Enemy());
            add(new Player());
        }
    }
```

a whole lot of nothing happens, when intuitively I think it should work. Am I missing something when it comes to generating instances of an Entity?

Comment: This cannot work because you're only checking if "Reset" has been pressed once, when the Level has been created. In order to react to Button presses, you could have an ENTER_FRAME handler running or alternatively a timer. In both of these approaches check in intervals(In ENTER_FRAME for every frame of your swf, in the timer to whatever you want) if the button has been pressed, and then react accordingly.

Comment: @DodgerThud I read up about the ENTER_FRAME handler but I seem unable to add any listeners, as it is seemingly an undefined method.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own solution, though I would still appreciate knowing how others would do the same.
As I use the FlashPunk library, I have access to tweens. My game is running at 60 FPS, so I used one on this level with a period of .0167 to check for a key press once every frame. The code is as follows, beginning with the class.

```
    public class Level extends World
{

    public function Level() 
    {
        var resetCheck:Tween = new Tween(.0167, Tween.LOOPING, reset);
        addTween(resetCheck,true)
        trace("World init");            
    }
    public function reset()
    {
        if (Input.pressed("Reset"))
        {
            removeAll();
            add(new Player());
            add(new Enemy());
            trace("RESET!!!");
        }
        if (Input.pressed("Spawn Enemy"))
        {
            add(new Enemy());
        }
    }

}
```